# How can I check whether file exists or not in specific folder in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, uri

this is my code,

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule application/public/.* - [L]
```

but when I entered to `localhost/css/style.css` it is 404 page, although `application/public/css/style.css` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^application/public/.* - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule .* /application/public/$0 [L]
```

The first rewriteRule prevent the following rule from being executed when the url starts with `/application/public/`. It also prevent the following rule from being applied more than once, although that is unlikely to happen in this specific case.

The second rule(-set) will internally redirect all request to the `/application/public/` folder, if and only if the requested filename/directory exists in that folder.

Comment: what is `-`? that you very much :D

Comment: `-` means `do nothing`. This, combined with the `L` flag, will stop processing of rules further down.